# How do I bind an AngularJS event to a PopSugar slider?

Tags: angularjs, slider

I am using [Popsugar AngularJS slider](https://github.com/PopSugar/angular-slider).

The documentation says that there are inputEvents (e.g mouseup/mousedown).

How can I bind a function to the slider's event in AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, the way to do this is to add `dragstop="true"` to the element, then make sure you have a watcher on the value(s) of the slider.  This will ensure the slider does not update the value(s) until the user lets go of the handle

Answer (score 0):

This answer put me on the right track when utilizing this.  I was, however using it within an ng-repeat which provided a bit of a challenge.  Here is how I solved that (in case someone else is also using it that way):

```
.directive('slider', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function($scope) {
            $scope.$watch('yourmodel.value', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if(newValue !== oldValue){
                    console.log('slider value changed');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

In my case I was not trying to usurp the power of the slider.  Just wanted to update a database when the value shifted.  Piggybacking onto the directive worked nicely for that.

Answer (score 0):

They've updated the library to add a change callback:
https://github.com/PopSugar/angular-slider

You can use it like this:

```
<slider floor="0" ceiling="100" step="1" ng-model="percent" change="onSliderChange(percent)"></slider>
```